# Why does Content-Security-Policy header calls "inline" scripts "unsafe"?

Tags: http, http-headers

Had to set `Content-Security-Policy` header to...

```
default-src https: 'unsafe-inline';
object-src 'none'
```

... for a single html page with no dependencies (with inline scripts) to run the `<script>` tag.

Why is inline considered unsafe?

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) inline are excluded but it doesn't say why, same in [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy).

Comment: Same question in Reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/AskProgramming/comments/115x1yb/why_does_contentsecuritypolicy_header_calls/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSP protects against XSS injections.

If a user is able to inject a `<script>` tag or `onclick`, because you forgot to escape user-input CSP will prevent that Javascript from running.

So for security purposes it can be good to just avoid any inline scripts altogether, so you can say: "Anything appearing in my HTML body is unintentional and should be blocked", and this is definitely a recommended practice.